# Graphical FTP client for Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, internet, ftp

I want a GUI-ish (and not command-line only) FTP client for Ubuntu. Any good you can recommed?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[Filezilla](http://filezilla.sourceforge.net).

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Gnome has a built-in FTP client, I think it's called "Connect to server". It will open a nautilus window that you can use exactly like a normal one.

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily call this an "FTP client", since people usually associate a client with a separate program, not a file manager extension. Even so, this a very good answer since the poster probably *isn't* looking for a separate client, but rather any GUI for using FTP.

Comment: @IlariKajaste I disagree. You can use Windows' Windows Explorer/File Explorer (file manager) as a full fledged FTP client. Have been able to for years. And I mean it makes sense. Think about it. Most File Managers have an "address bar" or "location bar" where you type in an address/location. And what's inside that location? Files! Seems like a perfect fit to me. :-)

Answer (score 4):

[**Fireftp**](http://fireftp.mozdev.org/) add-on for Firefox.

**Edit**
Screenshot removed as, although from the fireftp web site and functionally similar, it was not taken on an Ubuntu system and so objected to by some.

Apparently Fireftp it is not yet available for Firefox 3.5 so if you have moved your Ubuntu system to that version of Firefox it won't work (as of today).

Features include:

Secure: SSL/TLS/SFTP support

Synchronization: Keep directories in sync while navigating

Directory Comparison: Compare directory and subdirectory content

International: Available in over 20 languages

Character Set Support: UTF8 and just about any other character encoding supported

Automatic reconnect and resuming of transfers

Search/Filtering

Integrity Checks of transfers (XMD5, XSHA1)

Export/Import accounts

Remote Editing

File Hashing: Generate hashes of files (MD5, various SHA's)

Drag & Drop

File Compression: Using MODE Z

Timestamp Synchronization

Advanced properties (CHMOD, recursive CHMOD, thumbnails)

Comment: dude - windows screenshot. :)

Comment: -1 doesn't work with firefox 3

Comment: @flybywire Meanwhile it does work with Firefox 3.

Answer (score 4):

gFTP just works. It is easy to use and does the job.

Answer (score 0):

Konqueror comes with an FTP client.

Answer (score 0):

type `ftp://user:password@host` in Konqueror's location bar